# Conky - Set own variables

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, conky

How can i set own variables inside the conky config?
I want to define some own variables and then output they per echo.

I tried a lot but unfortuanly i don't know how to handle that.
Maybe someone can help me with that to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Conky can display the output from any script, or whatever shell commands you tell it, with these objects/variables (see `man conky`):

- ## exec command

  Executes a shell command and displays the output in conky.  Warning: this takes a lot more resources than other variables.  I’d recommend coding wanted behaviour in C/C++ and posting a patch.

  - There's also execi that only runs every "interval" seconds.
- ## execp command

  Executes  a shell command and displays the output in conky.  Warning: this takes a
  lot more resources than other variables.  I’d recommend coding wanted behaviour in
  C/C++  and  posting a patch.  This differs from $exec in that it parses the output
  of the command, so you can insert things like `${color  red}hi!${color}`  in  your
  script and have it correctly parsed by Conky.  Caveats: Conky parses and evaluates
  the output of $execp every time Conky loops, and then destroys  all  the  objects.
  If  you  try to use anything like $execi within an $execp statement, it will func‐
  tionally run at the same interval that the $execp statement runs, as it is created
  and destroyed at every interval.